# Segment Green color from a image

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-segmentation

I have an [image of a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNemj.png).

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(r'aa1.jpg') 


plt.imshow( image)
plt.show()

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  
plt.imshow( hsv)
plt.show()
```

Output is:

[image]

**Now, I am facing problem to find the optimal threshold value to segment the green region (alphabet A). How, can I do that for green, or any other colour. Or any other path to do that.**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function cv2.inRange

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
```

Like this:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Answer (score 0):

depending on the context of your problem, instead of thresholding, you coud try [color clustering via k-means](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html).
After clustering, you would take the pixels in the cluster wich center is closer to the color value you like.